# How to make a real "onchange" event in HTML (no jQuery)?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dom-events

Please note: I do not want to use `jQuery` for this (otherwise I like it)

**Problem:** I have come to situation where I need to do some javascript function after an user changes an input field (e.g. `input type="text"`). So I said to myself - I remember an `onchange` event - **BUT** `onchange` event runs AFTER user leaves the field, but I need the function to be called for example every time user types a character to that field. Wowhead shows nice example of what I am trying to achieve [this](http://www.wowhead.com/search?q=portal%20trainer) (field with placeholder "Search within results...")

**Summary:** I am looking for a SIMPLE way of detecting REAL `onchange` event([not the classic HTML one](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp))and through that call a JS function while not using jQuery?

Comment: You should listen to onkeyup events.

Comment: Be careful of just listening for keyboard events. Remember that a user can cut from and paste to the field using a pointing device.

Comment: @Alohci well thats a really good point! But fortunatelly, users have almost no way to copy it in my app :) and the whole mouse-listening thing is the whole issue itself :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following is a simple way of invoking each type of Key Press on field.

input type="text" onkeypress="myFunction()

Get Example here

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onkeypress

Enjoy..

you can also use onkeyup and onkeydown  instead of onkeypress.

Answer (score 10):

Use [onkeyup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.onkeyup) instead of onchange then.

Comment: YEAH ! That was EXACTLY what I was looking for! Thanks a lot! BTW: I knew this event but I really didnt expect it to act like that in a text field :-O Thanks a lot again :)

Answer (score 1):

Tried onkeypress="myFunction()" or onkeyup="myFunction()"?

There are also events for onfocus and onblur for entering and leaving a textfield :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use "input" event.  keyup and keypress don't work if a user modified the value only by a mouse.